# Quando é recomendado usar índices decrescentes?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, desempenho, índices

Por *default*, os bancos de dados relacionais criam índices usando estruturas de árvores binárias ordenadas de forma crescente. Porém existe a possibilidade de criá-lo de forma decrescente também.

Minha dúvida é se (e quando) é recomendado usá-lo. Por exemplo:

```
SELECT nome
FROM pessoa
WHERE data_cadastro >= '2014-01-01'
ORDER BY data_cadastro DESC
```

No SQL acima, considerando o `WHERE` e `ORDER BY`, um índice decrescente na coluna `data_cadastro` melhoraria o desempenho?

Comment: Por que tentaram fechar essa questão ?

Comment: @gmsantos O motivo escolhido foi "Baseada em Opiniões"

Comment: Bem coloquei uma resposta tentando explicar o básico de como a ordenação vai afetar selects e inserts. Acredito que isso esteja dentro do escopo da pergunta do OP e não é baseada em "opnião pessoal" mas em fatos de como funcionam os índices

Comment: Exato, @jean. Acredito que tenham se equivocado ao votar para fechar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende da sua necessidade.
Por default os índices são criados na ordem crescente porque, em geral, os valores (normalmente ids) são gerados de forma crescente. Desta forma os novos (maiores) valores vão para o fim da "lista". Isso diminui a chance de fragmentação do índice.

Exemplo:
Suponha que vc tem uma tabela onde o Id é autoident começando em 1 e acrescentando +1 a cada novo registro. Você define essa coluna como PK clustered mas muda a ordem do índice para decrescente.

Isso vai forçar page splits uma vez que cada novo registro vai forçar a reordenação da tabela.

Um cenário plausível para usar a ordenação decrescente poderia ser onde você faz poucos inserts mas costuma fazer muitos selects sobre os valores mais novos

Exemplo: Você tem um registro de reuniões em que vc compareceu e cria um índice ordenado pela data. Eventualmente uma nova reunião é inserida e você costuma apenas usar um select para retornar as reuniões da última semana.

Como sempre em SQL tudo depende. Na dúvida faça um acid teste. Experimente operações de select, insert, delete, update sobre a tabela em questão usando a ordenação das duas formas e tente medir as difereças de performance. Esse é realmente o único jeito de descobrir como melhorar a performance de um índice

Answer (score 2):

Imagine um índice em uma coluna de uma tabela agrupada:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
   pk INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   col1 INT NOT NULL
)
CREATE INDEX ix_mytable_col1 ON mytable (col1)
```

O índice em col1 mantém valores de col1 ordenados junto com as referências das linhas.

Uma vez que a tabela é agrupada, as referências às linhas são realmente os valores da pk. Eles também são ordenados dentro de cada valor de col1.

Isto significa que os índice estão ordenados em (col1, pk), e esta consulta:

```
SELECT  col1, pk
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
    col1, pk
```

Não precisa de ordenação!

Se criarmos o índice da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_mytable_col1_desc ON mytable (col1 DESC)
```

em seguida, os valores de col1 serão classificados descendente, mas os valores de pk dentro de cada valor de col1 serão classificados ascendente.

Isto significa que a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT  col1, pk
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
    col1, pk DESC
```

Pode ser servido por ix_mytable_col1_desc mas não por ix_mytable_col1.

Comment: "Não precisa de ordenação" pode levar incorretamente a presunção de que fazer um select sem order by vai retornar os valores ordenados pelo índice oquê não é garantido! Na verdade a engine vai ainda tentar ordenar de acordo com a definição do order by. Apenas vai ter bem menos trabalho ao faze-lo

Comment: Sim, sim! Mas isso já vai justamente dar menos trabalho. Dificilmente você faz um select sem order by hoje se for para exibição em tela...a não ser que utilizem frameworks que já ordenem automaticamente